# Add custom icon on specific point on google charts timeline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

I have a timeline using google react charts.

```
const columns = [
  { type: "string", id: "President" },
  { type: "string", id: "dummy bar label" },
  { type: "string", role: "tooltip" },
  { type: "date", id: "Start" },
  { type: "date", id: "End" }
];

const rows = [
  ["Washington", null, "George", new Date(1789, 3, 29), new Date(1797, 2, 3)],
  ["Adams", null, "John", new Date(1797, 2, 3), new Date(1801, 2, 3)],
  ["Jefferson", null, "Thomas", new Date(1801, 2, 3), new Date(1809, 2, 3)]
];
```

```
 <Chart
          chartType="Timeline"
          data={[columns, ...rows]}
          width="100%"
          height="400px"
        />
```

I want to add an icon to a specific day in the chart, on top of the bar (like in the image shown below).
[image: timeline with icon]

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/rakannimerreact-google-charts-timeline-with-tooltip-ry6yi